# What is the difference between std::move and unique_ptr::release?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am wondering why pstr2 is not null at the 4th line of STDOUT. AFAIK, move and release do not have ownership after a call.

```
  auto pstr = make_unique<string>(5, '*');
  cout << (pstr ? *pstr : "pstr is empty") << endl;
  auto pstr2(pstr.release());
  cout << (pstr ? *pstr : "pstr is empty") << endl;
  cout << (pstr2 ? *pstr2 : "pstr2 is empty") << endl;
  auto pstr3(move(pstr2));
  cout << (pstr2 ? *pstr2 : "pstr2 is empty") << endl;
  cout << (pstr3 ? *pstr3 : "pstr3 is empty") << endl;
```

The output is

```
*****
pstr is empty
*****
***** <-- my curious part.
*****
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable as `auto` for its type, its actual type is deduced from whatever value is assigned to the variable during its initialization.

The type of `pstr` is deduced as `unique_ptr<string>`, because that is what `make_unique<string>(5, '*')` returns.

`auto pstr2(pstr.release());` does not do what you think it does.  `release()` does not return a `unique_ptr<string>`, like you are expecting. It returns the raw `string*` pointer that was being held by `pstr`.  So, the type of `pstr2` is deduced as `string*`, not as `unique_ptr<string>` (and since `pstr` has given up its ownership of its `string*` pointer, you need to explicitly call `delete pstr2;` when you are done, or else the `string` object will be leaked).

Similar with `auto pstr3(move(pstr2));`.  Since `pstr2` is a raw `string*`, and `std::move()` is just a copy for a raw pointer, the type of `pstr3` is also deduced as `string*`, not as `unique_ptr<string>`.  `pstr2` and `pstr3` are pointing at the same `string` object in memory, which is why neither of them are null, and both output the same data to the console.

If you change the type of `pstr2` to replace the `auto` with `unique_ptr<string>` explicitly (or `decltype(pstr)`), then you will get the behavior you are expecting, eg:

```cpp
auto pstr = make_unique<string>(5, '*');
cout << (pstr ? *pstr : "pstr is empty") << endl;
unique_ptr<string> pstr2(pstr.release());
// or: decltype(pstr) pstr2(pstr.release());
cout << (pstr ? *pstr : "pstr is empty") << endl;
cout << (pstr2 ? *pstr2 : "pstr2 is empty") << endl;
auto pstr3(move(pstr2));
// or: decltype(pstr2) pstr3(move(pstr2));
cout << (pstr2 ? *pstr2 : "pstr2 is empty") << endl;
cout << (pstr3 ? *pstr3 : "pstr3 is empty") << endl;
```

Output

```
*****
pstr is empty
*****
pstr2 is empty
*****
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/p7fKPd)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are assuming that `pstr.release()` returns a `std::unique_ptr` whereas in the code as written it returns a `std::string *`.  Since this cannot be moved from, this explains the results you get.

If you change:

```
auto pstr2(pstr.release());
```

to:

```
auto pstr2 = unique_ptr<string>(pstr.release());
```

then you get the results you expect.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1SV2Wo7k2V0I5Ug5)

Answer (score 1):

Because pstr.release() returns a raw pointer, then pstr2 & pstr3 are deducated as raw pointers.

After compiling they are just like

```
unique_ptr<string> pstr = make_unique<string>(5, '*');
string* pstr2(pstr.release());
string* pstr3(move(pstr2));
```